# Reposurgeon makes obsolete all branches but master in a git tree

Tags: git, reposurgeon

After make stubmap has been finished. The next one is  make  which builds git repo. BUT I got only one branch and a folder with other branches. The problem is that other  branches are not visible in a git tree. What command should I use to make them git branches?
I thought that --branchify was the key but it did not work

`branchify trunk:branches/* <customproject.svn`

Here it is some examples I've found [GCC Migration](https://gitlab.com/esr/gcc-conversion), [Blender migration](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/blender-git-migration/-/tree/master)

Comment: Where are your branches located in SVN -- are they really in a top-level directory `branches`?

Comment: @AlexO nevermind, we decided to make own tools.